# String data conversion: Inserting data from Spinner using mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-spinner

I am trying to add data into MySQL database through spinner that has several options to choose. I do not know how to state value from spinner into MySQL code. The error occurs on the 39th line, which first line of Inserting Into database using MySQL code. I look forward to hearing from you soon.

```
<?php

include 'db.php';    


        $user_type = ['user_type'];
        $first = $_POST['first'];
        $last = $_POST['last'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone']; 


        if(/*$user_type == '' ||*/ $first == '' || $last == '' || $email == '' || $username == ''  || $password == '' || $phone == '')
        {
            echo 'Please, fill all fields';

        } else{
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username='$username'";
                $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,$sql));
            if(isset($check))
            {
                    echo 'Username already exist. Please, use another one.';
            }else{
                        $hashedPWD = password_hash($password , PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //hash password

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_type, user_first, user_last, user_email, user_username, user_pwd, user_phonenumber) VALUES('$user_type','$first','$last','$email','$username','$hashedPWD','$phone')";
                    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
                    {
                        echo 'Successfully registered';

                    } else{

                        echo 'Oops! Please try again!';
                        }   
                    }

            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
```

Comment: remove single quotes in values and try

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Removing single quotes does not helped. The error is following:Array to string conversion in line 39

Comment: show your exact error message  .. and also the table users schema  ..

Comment: Use prepared statements..

Comment: This is exact error that I am getting [link](http://prntscr.com/j89b7w)

Comment: Instead of data options in spinner, I am getting in user_type field in database "Array" statement.